# Custom SecurityTokenHandler for WIF

Tags: c#, .net, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I am trying to implement a custom `SecurityToken` and [SecurityTokenHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandler.aspx) for a STS using Microsoft.IndentityModel (= Windows Indentity Foundation).

The token is serialized to a simple xml document with signature (using a X509 certificate) and is sometimes (not always) encrypted (depends on the target realm).

Till now it worked quite well, but i got stuck on [SecurityTokenHandler.CreateSecurityTokenReference(SecurityToken token, bool attached)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandler.createsecuritytokenreference.aspx) which should return a `SecurityKeyIndetifierClause`.

My question is: What is a `SecurityKey`, `SecurityKeyIndentifier` and [SecurityKeyIndentifierClause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitykeyidentifierclause%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in general and for my sceanrio (rsa signed (and encrypted) xml token) in specific?

There is almost no documentation in MSDN and I couldn't find anything else helpful on this topic.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I know the easiest and recommended way is to use a build in token format like saml, but the token is evaluated by a legacy system which expects a specific format i have no influence on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime I found answers to the questions my self:

**SecurityKey**

A SecurityKey is used for cryptographic operations. This is not needed by bearer token implementations. Therefore you can just return an empty list in the corresponding property of the *SecurityToken*:

```
public override ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityKey> SecurityKeys
{
    get { return new List<SecurityKey>().AsReadOnly(); }
}
```

**SecurityKeyIdentifierClause**

As already pointed out by the other answer a *SecurityKeyIdentifierClause* is kind of the unique identifier of a security token. It is used by a *SecurityTokenResolver* to return the corresponding *SecurityToken* for a specified *SecurityKeyIdentifierClause*.

Probably the best solution for your own *SecurityTokenHandler* implementation is to return a [LocalIdKeyIdentifierClause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.localidkeyidentifierclause.aspx) with the id of your token as *localId* parameter:

```
public override SecurityKeyIdentifierClause CreateSecurityTokenReference(SecurityToken token, bool attached)
{
    if (token == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("token");

    return new LocalIdKeyIdentifierClause(token.Id);
}
```

**SecurityKeyIdentifier**

A *SecurityKeyIdentifier* is a collection of *SecurityKeyIdentifierClauses*. When ever needed you can use the implementation in *System.IdentityModel.Tokens* here. There is usually no need to take care of this by your self.

Answer (score 0):

The key identifiers are used with custom tokens to do a couple things.  They describe the token, and/or point to other related tokens (because tokens can just be pointers - perhaps for performance reasons et al).  if you do not need key identifier, you can do two things:

- Return false from CanWriteKeyIdentifierClause:

  public override bool CanWriteKeyIdentifierClause(SecurityKeyIdentifierClause securityKeyIdentifierClause)
  {
  return false;
  }
- Return a default (or null) value from CreateSecurityTokenReference:

  public override SecurityKeyIdentifierClause CreateSecurityTokenReference(SecurityToken token, bool attached)
  {
  return default(SecurityKeyIdentifierClause);
  }